# Xamarin Forms Bluetooth Socket MaxReceivePacketSize == 0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-bluetooth

So, im trying to make an app that syncs the clipboard from the pc to an android phone, but there's a problem: the phone can send messages to the pc and this one receive it, but not the other way around. I tried a lot of things, like asking for more permissions related to bluetooth on the phone-side, but it didn't do much. The thing that made me wonder what the problem was is the MaxReceivePacketSize from the BluetoothSocket (Android.Bluetooth), which value was 0 every time. Since it's readonly, i wanted to see why is it 0 and if it's the problem. Here's my code:

Phone-side:

```
try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                await WifiPermissionAsync();
                socket.OutputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetLocalIpAddress())); //this works

                Console.WriteLine($"{socket.MaxReceivePacketSize}");

                // read data while it's connected
                while (socket.IsConnected)
                {
                    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // this doesnt

                    if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Length > 0)
                    {
                        var receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        await ShowAlert($"Message Received:", receivedData, "ok");

                        buffer = new byte[1024];
                    }
                    else await Task.Delay(10);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Error handling connection: " + ex.Message); }
```

PC-side (im using InTheHand.Net for bluetooth):

set-connection:

```
Guid uuid = new("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

                    BluetoothEndPoint endPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(p.DeviceAddress, uuid);
                    
                    bt.Connect(endPoint);

                    if (bt.Connected)
                    {
                        btS = bt.GetStream();
                        Clipboard_Initialize();
                    }
```

Send_Data:

```
if (bt.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Clipboard.GetText());

                        bt.Client.Send(buffer);
                        btS.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        btS.Socket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    }
                    else if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new();
                        Clipboard.GetImage().Save(ms, Clipboard.GetImage().RawFormat);
                        byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();

                        btS.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show($"rip: {ex.Message}"); }
            }
```

Just to remark, i want to get the phone to receive the messages from the pc, so I can programm those messages to be entered on the clipboard of the phone